# Masstransit/RabbitMQ legacy MVC 4.6.2 solution can't publish messages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, masstransit

We've a legacy MVC website C# 4.6.1. In a brand new project MVC 4.6.1 it works just fine.

In the legacy solution I try to call

`busControl.Start();`

And it gets stuck there, but it never times out, so I don't have also any error message or any other lead to figure out the problem.

Is there a way to debug Masstransit ?

Any known issues related to this ?

Thanks !

Comment: No known issues, if you have logging integrated to your solution (using ILoggerFactory) MassTransit will write to those logs so you can see if there are connection issues. My guess is the application can't connect to the broker and is retrying. Passing a cancellationToken to `StartAsync`, or specifying a timeout calling `Start`, should give you an exception after the timeout expires or the token is canceled.

Comment: Thanks ! 'm using 4.6.1 and Masstransit 6.3.2, I'ven't been able to add logging, it did produced an exception when trying to connect after I added a timeout.
Definetely something is preventing the connection, even though as I mention before in a clean project it works just fine. I'll keep looking thanks for the advice.